# Ignite Apache: nodes discovery and communication behind NAT

Tags: ignite, nat

I am running a cluster of several Ignite nodes. Each node running on a separate servers as a docker container.
In `IgniteConfiguration` I set localhost as non-loopback address (which is a container IP address set by docker) + each node is placed behind a NAT, so I also define `AddressResolver` (simply to have mapping between NAT <--> docker_container).

Each node starts with similar message, for example

```
>>> VM name: 62@ignite01
>>> Ignite instance name: ignite-node-1
>>> Local node [ID=FEDF34FE-2AD7-4A92-BDF2-BEERF36AC79, order=28, clientMode=false]
>>> Local node addresses: [ignite01/192.168.1.18]
```

Here `ignite01` is a alias in etc/hosts, `192.168.1.XX` is docker container address.

When nodes discover each other I can see `NODE_JOINED` messages, for example

```
[evt=NODE_JOINED, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=b283asde-7c68-6789-96cb-152bdaf0aadb, addrs=ArrayList [192.168.1.16], sockAddrs=HashSet [ignite02/10.10.1.5:47500, /192.168.1.16:47500],
```

Which means that node will use both addresses to communicate with remote node: NAT (10.10.1.5) and internal container address (192.168.1.16, which is never reachable).
Thus I have delays at startup and long timeouts when node fails to communicate (since both addresses are tried)

Is there any way I can remove unreachable addresses during discovery (by somehow configuring `IgniteConfiguration`), so nodes will use only NAT addresses to communicate with each other?
At this point I only found a way to manipulate (via Reflection API in java) `sockAddrs` list (in `TcpDiscoveryNode` class) in discovery messages when discovery process starts. And it all works fine, but I am not sure if it's the safe way.

I tried to reconfigure many times `IgniteConfiguration`, but I couldn't get rid of local container addresses from discovery messages and at the same time make whole cluster work again.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `localAddress` property that was designed for such a case.

More details in [the docs](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/network-configuration)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. If in `TcpDiscoverySpi` I set `localAddress` (as external to container address, in my case that's NAT 10.10.1.5) Ignite won't start. 
It will fail with an exception `"org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to bind TCP server socket (possibly all ports in range are in use)"`